# mod_rewrite URL masking is not cooperating

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^task/(.*)/?$ index.php?mode=task&id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

If the last line is included, **no matter what is put in the URL** it sets $_GET['mode'] to **index.php**. Without the last line included, or if I set it to go to index.php?mode=home, for instance, it works fine, but there isn't a catchall.

I don't see what the problem is, but it's probably something simple. If someone else could take a moment to steer me right, that'd b great. Thanks!

Comment: Surely those `RewriteCond`s will mean that nothing with match - a request is either for a file or a directory, you are saying 'do not match either'. This means the last rule will always match, because the first rule can never match, and the last rule should match anything... Or have a missed something?

Comment: -f and -d mean "if file does not exist" and "if directory does not exist" respectively, afaik, not "is the request a file" or "is the request a directory". As I said, without the last line, or if I set the mode=home in the last line, it works fine.

Comment: Ok apologies, just re-read the docs for `RewriteCond` - never used it that much, `RewriteRule` is usually enough for me. Seems a very odd problem - is there any way you can test this on another server? I just tried this on my PC's local Apache 2.2.17/Win32 install and I don't have the problem (`$_GET['mode']` is populated with the path, not with `index.php`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply that to ,say, `/task/123`, this is what happens, (assuming that URI doesn't exist):

1. passes !-f, /task/123 isn't a file that exists
2. passes !-d, /task/123 isn't a directory that exists
3. MATCH against `^task/(.*)/?$` so the URI gets rewritten to `index.php?mode=task&id=123`
4. With [L], nothing else happens and the request gets INTERNALLY REDIRECTED to `index.php?mode=task&id=123`
5. Internal redirect gets all rules re-applied <--- this is what's screwing you up
6. no match against `^task/(.*)/?$`, do nothing
7. MATCH against `^(.*)/?$`, so the URI gets rewritten to `index.php?mode=index.php`
8. initial URL equal rewritten URL: index.php, stop rewriting

What you need to do is add a condition to the 2nd rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I hadn't thought of it like that. It seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I ended up having to change: **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php** to: **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php**